# Countrows including a slicer

Tags: count, powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop, slicers

I have those 4 tables:

[image]

I am sorry for the german - englisch naming. My predecessor started german and I am trying to shift it into english. You can just call them:

***'Place'***,
***'Streets'***,
***'Usage'*** and
***DateTime'***

***'DateTime'*** is actually just a calendar with dates from 2014 to 2025 and 96 times for each date (every time in 15 minute steps)

***'Usage'*** gives me the IDs of charging stations which get used (***'Usage'[LPNumber]***) and the start- and endtime of the usage.

With this Code:

```
TimesOverlapping = 
CALCULATE (
    COUNTROWS ( 'Usage' );
    FILTER (
        'Usage';
        'Usage'[ConnectionStart Time] < ( DateTime[Time] + TIME ( 0; 14; 59 ) )
        && 'Usage'[ConnectionEnd Time] > DateTime[Time]
        && 'Usage'[ConnectionStart Day] = DateTime[Date]
    )
)
```

I am counting the number of charging stations (in ***'Usage'***) which get used, for example on 01.01.2014 from 00:00 to 00:15 (I always sum up 15 minutes) and display the number as custom column in ***'DateTime'*** in the row which says 01.01.2014 00:00. This works totally fine.

Now my problem:

I can use a date slicer because I have all the dates in ***'DateTime'*** but now I also need to apply a place- and a street slicer to filter the values in ***'DateTime'*** but I do not have any direct connections (as you can see) and it is not possible to create any or to rewrite the tables because they have a lot of impact on other tables.

My thoughts: I already have a code which gives values from ***'Usage'*** to ***'DateTime'*** (see above) and we can filter ***'Usage'*** by place and street. Wouldn't it be possible to only give the filtered values to ***'DateTime'*** or does any other workaround exist?

I found a similar problem in the power bi community but I couldn't get use of it and I don't know if I am allowed to post liks. The headline was "Use slicer to filter countrows-table".

I appreciate your help a lot! Thank you very much.

Comment: Have you tried using Bi-Directional Filters on the relationships?

Comment: I just tried it. I had to uncheck "Make this relationship active" to select "Both" for "Cross filter direction". It still works exactly the same. I can't apply place and street filters via slicer.